# Create object with duplicate keys

Tags: javascript

In Javascript, how can I create this object without overwriting the keys with equal names.
When the object is displayed, the keys override..

```
var dip = {
    qtd: 6,
    lce: {
        'oct': {
            'sgs': 1,
            'ucs': 1
        },
        'oct': {
            'sgs': 2,
            'ucs': 2
        }
    }
};
console.log(dip);

//Result of console.log
{
    qtd: 6,
    lce: {      
        'oct': {
            'sgs': 2,
            'ucs': 2
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not possible.... either unique keys or use an array

Comment: Why create 2 properties with same name?

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem. What are you actually trying to do? Ask that question and you'll get better answers than trying to ask about what you think is the solution. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: You cant repeat keys. They will always overwrite. 

transform lce in a array of 'oct' with the corresponding values. 

var dip = {
    qtd: 6,
    lce: [
         {
            'sgs': 1,
            'ucs': 1
        },
        {
            'sgs': 2,
            'ucs': 2
        }
    ]
};

Comment: To add to mariodiniz, if you want to maintain the 'oct' key, just have the value of that key be an array. var dip = { qtd: 6, lce: {'oct': [ { 'sgs': 1, 'ucs': 1 }, { 'sgs': 2, 'ucs': 2 } ] } };

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, you can't. And it wouldn't make sense if you could either. The problem is that if you have multiple objects that have the same key, and you go back to access one of them later, which one would it be pointing too? The idea behind keys is that it references one, and only one object.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Maybe `lce` should point to an array of objects. If the `oct` stuff is essential it could look like this:

```
var dip = {
  qtd: 6,
  lce: [
    { 'sgs': 1,
      'ucs': 1,
      'oct': true
    },
    { 'sgs': 2,
      'ucs': 2,
      'oct': true
    }
  ]
}
```